# Align Title Left React Chart.js V2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2, react-chartist

I'm trying to align the title to the left instead of the center (shown in the image).

I know this is possible on chartJS `v3.0.0-alpha.2`, but `reactchartjs` only goes up to `2.9.30` as far as I know.

Does anyone know how to achieve this in `reactchartjs`?

I thought it would be something like:

```
options={{
      title: {
        position: 'top',
        align: 'left',
      },
    }}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Display of graph]

Comment: It is not supported in version 2.x, version 3 is still in beta.

If you want it you either have to switch to the basic version of the lib where you can so it and write your own wrapper or you will need to pass an empty string to the title so it creates the space, after that you can write a custom plugin which will place the title on the canvas in the spot where you like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `align` parameter. This sets the alignment of the title. Your options are:

- `start`
- `center`
- `end`

Your `align: 'left'` isn't one of the above and will not have any effect. Setting `align: 'start'` however will give you exactly what you want:

[image]

The full code looks like this:

```
<Chart 
    type='line' 
    data={dat} 
    options={{
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                align: 'start',
                text: 'Bitcoin Mining Difficulty'
            }
        }
    }} />
```

Let me also mention that you should not confuse that with `position: 'left'`. `position` moves the whole title into one of `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` area of the chart. An example with a combination of `position: 'left'` and `align: start`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Chart.js Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterDraw` hook to draw the title yourself directly on the canvas using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText).

In React, you can [register the plugin](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2#chartjs-object) as follows:

```
componentWillMount() {
  Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: chart => {
      let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      ctx.textAlign = "left";
      ctx.font = "14px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillText("Title", xAxis.left, 10);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  });
}
```

You'll also have to define some extra padding at the top of the chart to make sure, the title appears on the `canvas`.

```
options: {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      top: 20
    }
  }, 
  ...
```

Please take a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chartjs-2-left-align-title?file=index.js) and see how it works.