# react-chartjs-2 how to show legend text on the left with vertical text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, legend, react-chartjs

I just want to align the Chart Legend on the right and the text will be shown vertically.
Goal:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mluZ9.png)

I've tried to use: position: left
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAKW5.png)
The legend already move to the left. But I don't know how to align the text vertically
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI9rk.png)

Ex:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMZn7.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, you want to show title to left of chart.
In your output, I expect:

```
const commonOptions: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    interaction: {
           intersect: false,
    },
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'right',
      },
      title: {
                display: true,
                align: 'center',
                text: 'Study Count',
                position: 'left'
            }
    }
  },
```

Try in:

> https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/vertical.html

Good lucks

Comment: I mean, want to align vertically all the legends

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMZn7.png

Comment: You can use `afterDraw` to custom legend label. Pls check this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099477/align-title-left-react-chart-js-v2). As @uminder's answer, he using `CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillText()` to custom. Beside, you can use `context.rotate()` to make vertical text